# Comparing numbers and dates in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file with numbers and dates that I need to compare back to values from today. The layout of the file is basic comma delimited, here is an excerpt:

```
21,2017-11-22
22,2017-11-23
23,2017-11-24
24,2017-11-27
27,2017-11-28
28,2017-11-29
29,2017-11-30
```

I have a Python script that needs to compare the first value in each line with today's date. If the values match then I will use the date from that same line to perform the next step. The problem is I cannot get the date from today to match the number in the text file. Here is my script:

```
import datetime

a = open("NovemberDates.txt","r")
current = datetime.date.today()
day = current.day

from datetime import datetime

while True:
    line = a.readline()
    splitline = line.split(",")
    number = splitline[0]
    date = splitline[1]
    if number == day:
        print ('TODAY!!')
    else:
        print ('NOPE')
    input('Press enter to continue: ')
    if not line:
        break
```

Running this script today, 11/27/2017, I would expect to get a printed message "TODAY!!" when the script reaches line 5 of the text file; 27,2017-11-28. But I am still getting "NOPE" which tells me Python does not recognize `day = current.day`as 27.

What do I need to do to get these two values to match?

Comment: Maybe you could print repr() of the values so as to debug your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of `number` is string but the type of `day` is int. 
You need to change the type of one of this variables. 
Replace `number == day` by `int(number) == day` or `number == str(day)`

Comment: louis - that works perfect. thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 4):

`number` is a string but `day` is an `int`. They can never be equal since Python doesn't autocoerce types.

Change `number = splitline[0]` to `number = int(splitline[0])` and be ready to catch a `ValueError` in case `splitline[0]` can't be converted to an `int`.

Alternatively, as @highlycaffeinated suggested, you can convert `day` to a string: 
`day = str(current.day)`.

This has 2 benefits:
The conversion will be done once, and no `ValueError` will be raised (since essentially anything can be converted to a string).

Comment: would it be better to convert `day` to a string to a) only do the conversion once, and b) avoid the failed conversion (`ValueError`) scenario?

Comment: @highlycaffeinated , yeah, it would.

Answer (score 0):

get the day today in the same format

```
import datetime
d = datetime.datetime.today()
datetoday = d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

make sure that the data from the file contains no trailing whitespace

```
date = splitline[1].strip()
```

then use this `datetoday` to compare with `date` (`splitline[1].strip()`) in your loop

Finally don't use "while True" read the data in a for loop.  Like this

```
import datetime

a = open("NovemberDates.txt","r")
d = datetime.datetime.today()
datetoday = d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

from datetime import datetime

for line in a:
   splitline = line.split(",")
   number = int(splitline[0])
   date = splitline[1].strip()
   if datetoday == date:
       print ('TODAY!!')
       print ("the magic number is %d"%number)
       break
   else:
       print ('NOPE')
```